# bootstrap 4 navbar has padding on left and right side

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, I know I can add the CSS to take away the padding from the parent div but I thought that bootstrap would make the navbar the full width of the page? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="outer">
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="\movieTheater.jpg" width="10%" height="10%" alt="">
          Movie Theater
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: or just use `nav` tag before `container-fluid` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **container-fluid** class is 100% wide, but it has some padding applied. To manage the padding you can use `p-*` classes from **Bootstrap 4** (read the [spacing section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/) from the documentation). In your particular case, you need the `p-0`class to remove the padding. As an extra, I have added the collpase menu button, if you don't include it your `navbar` will not work correctly when collapsed. Check the next example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="outer">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="\movieTheater.jpg" width="10%" height="10%" alt=""> Movie Theater
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: once I add `padding 0` to the `container-fluid` the horizontal scroll appears